# Why do my all JSP <script> design/appearance section change in my NetBeans7.3.1?

Tags: netbeans-7, appearance

I have JSP files in NetBeans, and these JSPs' have `<script>...</script>` sections.
These sections' design or appearance was colorful as you can see in the following picture (red rectangle):

[image: appearance1]

But from today, the colors are missing, the script sections are only white, like in the picture:

[image: appearance2]

Why is it? I've closed netbeans, and restarted my computer, but it is white. Please help me to set back the colorful of the jsps' script sections. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of script tag to type="text/javascript" and possibly restart NetBeans. Then it should be OK. According to RFC 2616, media types are case sensitive so text/JavaScript is something different than text/javascript (although both could be working in browsers due to their benevolence)

Edit: The same could apply to the language attribute